# ul li in two columns make my second column disappear on hover

Tags: css, carousel, multiple-columns

Hre is my situation:

I have a carousel slider which i d like to display the list in two columns.

when I use:

```
ul.pl-bxslider.pl-box-car {-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 2.5em;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 2.5em;
 column-count: 2;
 column-gap: 2.5em;
```

}

Its good, display in two columns, However, If i hover an element from the second column, this one disappear on this moment . . ..

Also the list is not being display in the good order . . . anybody has some highlite to make this work correctly ?

I have try another solution like that:

```
ul.pl-bxslider.pl-box-car li {float: left !important;display:table;width: 50% !important;}
```

It also work, I don't have those problem, but instead, the carousel doesnt slide correctly anymore . . ..

Any help would be awesome,

Thank you for your time !

----- EDIT -----

ok, I fixed it by adding to the li element the following:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

-webkit-transform: translateX(0);

Otherwise , I have still the probem of order which is incorrect :(

Comment: Maybe a JSfiddle of your problem would help?

Comment: @tiibewww: Please create and share a jsFiddle. Can't help you with only the CSS mentioned.

Comment: I'm using wordpress with a plugin . . . So i can not really create a JS Fiddle unfortunatly :( :(

Comment: I have edit my question as i managed to fix it, but not the order of my li element :(

Comment: can you please post your html code